# Whats wrong in this method for calculating volume of truncated sphere?

Tags: calculus

Assume a truncated sphere (R) with angle from centre to the top and bottom disc as theta1 and theta2 , now differential volume of disc would be ( by considering a angle theta from top disc ) dV= piR^2sin^2theta.Rdtheta, R dtheta is width of disc. Now integrating from theta1 to pi-theta2 it should give the result. But it fails even for the simple full sphere case , whats going wrong here ?

Comment: You have been around for almost a year. Haven't you yet noticed that you are supposed to use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) around here?

Comment: Oh sry Sir i will edit it a bit later

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got the cross-sectional area correct, but the height by which you multiply it is $|dz|$ where $z=R\cos\theta$. Thus the proper differential to integrate is

$(\pi R^2\sin\theta)(R\sin\theta d\theta)=\pi R^3\sin^3\theta d\theta$.

This is integrated by rendering

$\sin^3\theta=\sin^2\theta\sin\theta=(1-\cos^2\theta)\sin\theta$

and then plugging in $u=\cos\theta(=z/R)$, which absorbs the remaining $\sin\theta$ factor into the differential and leaves you with only a polynomial integration. You should then get the proper volume, including for the whole sphere.